# Given vectors $\vec p$, $\vec q$, and $\vec r$, such that $|\vec p| = |\vec q| = |\vec r| = 3$ units?

Tags: calculus, vectors

And $\vec p$ bisects the $60^o$ degree angle formed by $\vec q$ and $\vec r$, express $\vec p$ as a linear combination of $\vec q$ and $\vec r$

Answer: $$\vec p = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \vec r + \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \vec q$$

**How do I solve this?**

Attempt:

$$\vec p = a\vec q + b\vec r$$

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: the vectors $\vec p$,$\vec q$ and $\vec r$ can form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @K.Rmth yes but what does that tell us?

Comment: Draw the triangle and then you will see that $\vec p$ is the sum of the respective projections of vectors $\vec q$ and $\vec r$ onto $\vec p$(or the line collinear to $\vec p$)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\vec p \cdot \vec q = a\vec q \cdot \vec q + b\vec r \cdot \vec q$$
$$\vec p \cdot \vec r = a\vec q \cdot \vec r + b\vec r \cdot \vec r$$

Now use for all dot products in there the formula
$$u \cdot v = |u| |v| \cos(\theta) \,.$$

Once you calculate all dot products you get a system of two equations with the unknowns $a$ and $b$. Solve it.